# how can i read json in jquery

Tags: jquery, json

```
{
    "Employment_from_date":[
        "From Date cannot be blank."
    ],
    "Employment_to_date":[
        "To Date cannot be blank."
    ],
    "Employment_company":[
        "Company cannot be blank."
    ],
    "Employment_designation":[
        "Designation cannot be blank."
    ]
}
```

Comment: If that's in a string, use `obj = $.parseJSON(string);`. If it's a literal in the code, you don't need to do anything to read it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var json= 
{
    "Employment_from_date":[
        "From Date cannot be blank."
    ],
    "Employment_to_date":[
        "To Date cannot be blank."
    ],
    "Employment_company":[
        "Company cannot be blank."
    ],
    "Employment_designation":[
        "Designation cannot be blank."
    ]
};

$.each(json,function(key,item)
 {
    alert(key + " = "+ item);
});
```

Comment: I've written like this but not working in my side. can u help me pls?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/d6dm66ut/